# Load all documents from RavenDB

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I have this model:

```
namespace Model
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public Category()
        { }

        public Category(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

When I store a document and retrieve it, the result is a list of documents with zero elements:

```
using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    session.Store(category);
    session.SaveChanges();
    var categories = session.Query<Model.Category>().ToList();
}
```

category get the proper id, that is "1". But when I do the Query, then I do not get any elements.

If I Load the document:

```
var category = session.Load<Model.Document>("categories/1")
```

Instead of the Query, I get the proper category.

How do I load all documents from Raven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

I have to wait for non staled results. So if I change my Query out with this:

```
session.Query<Model.Category>().Customize(cr => cr.WaitForNonStaleResults()).ToList();
```

it works just fine.

Comment: yes, this is standard behavior for a unit test.  You don't want to do this in production though.  Read more [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/stale-indexes).